# Silverlight MessageBox.Show blocking WCF service call in BackgroundWorker

Tags: silverlight-2.0, messagebox

When a MessageBox is being displayed from Silverlight, any calls to a WCF service being executed in a BackgroundWorker are blocked.  The OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog allows these calls to go through.  Is the browser (IE7) blocking network access during a MessageBox?

We can create our own modal window, but this causes developer code to change as it must be asynchronous. (developer code does not stop while custom "MessageBox" is displayed)

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you design your application in such a way as to avoid the use of a modal messagebox? Perhaps use a Popup - you can make these act as a modal dialog by covering the entire app in a grid and forcing keyboard navigation to cycle within the popup.

See [Shawn Wildermuth's page](http://wildermuth.com/2008/05/01/Creating_a_Pseudo-Dialog_with_Silverlight_s_Popup_Control.aspx) for all the details.